# Insert json data to database using preparestatement

Tags: java, mysql, json

I have json data like this

```
{
  "name": "ABCD",
  "age": "43",
  "DateOfBirth": "2000-10-10"
}
```

Both its key and value are surrounded by double quote. Now I need to insert this to my database.

```
 name : varchar
 age : integer
 DateOfBirth : Date
```

Using a gson, I convert the json data to a HashMap (String,String)  but now What should I use with prepareStatement , setString() or setObject() ? Will they make sure that works with all DBMS ( MySql,Postgres,SQlserver...)

Comment: What are you using to persist your data? JDBC? Hibernate?

Comment: You will have to write in your own query and run it through your prepareStatement.

Comment: @shinjw: Yes, I know but I asked what I should use ,setString() or setObject().

Comment: Since you're using a HashMap, you would use setString()

Comment: But does it guarantee that it works in all cases and all DBMS? I mean there must be implicit conversion right?

Comment: It depends on your query. Not all syntax are the same across all DBMS.

Comment: suppose that my query is a simple and standard one : "Insert into person(name,age,date) values(?,?,?);

Comment: @user2747502 after getting the data into a HashMap, you still need to write some code to replace HashMap's toString(). After that, just use the PreparedStatement.setString() using yourMap.toString() as a value. The problem of course is that you want the json format for a non-json string, so you'll have to write everything again (and how will you deal with escaped chars?)